# Transfer file to server using POST method

Tags: swift, http, server

This my first attempt to send file to a server. I've set the necessary setting info.plist (allow arbitary load is set to TRUE) but I kept getting a 405 error.

Detail error

> A request was sent to a virtual directory using the HTTP verb POST and the default document is a static file that does not support HTTP verbs other than GET or HEAD.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let statusLabel = UILabel()
        statusLabel.text = "Uploading..."
        statusLabel.textAlignment = .center
        statusLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 30)
        statusLabel.center = view.center
        view.addSubview(statusLabel)
        
        // Call the uploadFile function with your parameters here
        uploadFile(fileName: "patient", fileExtension: "json", endpoint: "http://www.bigland.jp/", directoryPath: "/PatientData/")
    }
    

    
    func uploadFile(fileName: String, fileExtension: String, endpoint: String, directoryPath: String) {
        // Get the URL of patient.json in the app's bundle
        if let patientURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: fileExtension) {
            var data = Data()

            // generate boundary string using a unique per-app string
            let boundary = UUID().uuidString

            let session = URLSession.shared

            // Set the URLRequest to POST and to the specified URL
            var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: endpoint)!)
            urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"

            // Set Content-Type Header to multipart/form-data, with the boundary
            urlRequest.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

            // Add the file data to the raw http request data
            data.append("\r\n--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
            data.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"\(directoryPath)/patient.json\"\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
            data.append("Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)

            // Read the contents of patient.json and append it to data
            do {
                let fileData = try Data(contentsOf: patientURL)
                data.append(fileData)
            } catch {
                print("Error reading patient.json: \(error)")
                return
            }

            data.append("\r\n--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)

            // Send a POST request to the URL, with the data we created earlier
            session.uploadTask(with: urlRequest, from: data) { responseData, response, error in
                if error == nil {
                    if let jsonData = responseData,
                       let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
                        print(jsonString)
                    }
                } else {
                    print("Error uploading file: \(error)")
                }
            }.resume()
        } else {
            print("patient.json not found in the app's bundle")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI - you are not using UIKit to post the file. You are using Foundation (which contains URLSession and related classes).

Comment: The error message says that the URL you are trying to POST to doesn't accept POST.  It is a read-only url that only accepts GET requests.  You can't just POST data at a web server.  You need some server-side process to accept the POST request and process it.